# Why my filtering my listview populated from sqlite database doesn't work?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite, adapter

when I run the app the listview is populated from the database and it's fine but when I want to filter the adapter based on what I write in the edittext nothing happens also there is nothing in the logcat.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Search extends ListFragment implements TextWatcher {
    Adapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Item> myList = new ArrayList<Item>();
    ListView myListView;
    Databasehelper myDbHelper;
    LinearLayout not_found;
    EditText edtSeach;
    Button searchbtn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search, container, false);
        edtSeach = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.calc_txt_Prise);
        edtSeach.addTextChangedListener(this);
        searchbtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.searchbtn);
        not_found = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_not_found);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        myDbHelper = new Databasehelper(getActivity());
        myDbHelper.openDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.QueryData("select * from zankodict");
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Item itemm = new Item();
                    itemm.setId(cursor.getString(0));
                    itemm.setEng(cursor.getString(1));
                    itemm.setKurd(cursor.getString(2));
                    itemm.setAr(cursor.getString(3));
                    itemm.setFa(cursor.getString(4));
                    itemm.setTr(cursor.getString(5));
                    myList.add(itemm);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            adapter = new Adapter(getActivity(), R.layout.single_row, myList);
            myListView = getListView();
            myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            myDbHelper.closeDataBase();
            myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String localObject0 = Search.this.myList.get(position).getId();
                    String localObject1 = Search.this.myList.get(position).getEng();
                    String localObject2 = Search.this.myList.get(position).getKurd();
                    String localObject3 = Search.this.myList.get(position).getAr();
                    String localObject4 = Search.this.myList.get(position).getFa();
                    String localObject5 = Search.this.myList.get(position).getTr();
                    myDbHelper.openDatabase();
                    myDbHelper.insertRow2(localObject0, localObject1, localObject2, localObject3,localObject4,localObject5);
                    myDbHelper.closeDataBase();
                    Intent localIntent;
                    localIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), MyResults.class);
                    localIntent.putExtra("enG", localObject1);
                    localIntent.putExtra("kurD", localObject2);
                    localIntent.putExtra("aR", localObject3);
                    getActivity().startActivity(localIntent);
                }
            });
        }
        searchbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyTask searchAsyn = new MyTask();
                searchAsyn.cancel(true);
                searchAsyn.execute("seachdb",edtSeach.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        MyTask searchAsyn = new MyTask();
        searchAsyn.cancel(true);
        searchAsyn.execute("seachdb",s.toString());    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,ArrayList<Item>> {
        ArrayList<Item> fillarary;
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Item> doInBackground(String... params) {
            String searchwd = params[1];
            String methods = params[0];
            if(methods.equals("seachdb")){
               fillarary = fillList(searchwd);
            }
            return fillarary;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Item> fill) {
            myListView.setAdapter(new Adapter(getActivity(), R.layout.single_row, fill));
            validateItemCount();
        }
        public ArrayList<Item> search (String keyword){
            ArrayList<Item> searcharray = null;
            myDbHelper.openDatabase();
            Cursor cursor2 = myDbHelper.QueryData("select * from zankodict WHERE eng LIKE '%"+ keyword + "%'");
            if (cursor2 != null) {
                if (cursor2.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        Item itemm = new Item();
                        itemm.setId(cursor2.getString(0));
                        itemm.setEng(cursor2.getString(1));
                        itemm.setKurd(cursor2.getString(2));
                        itemm.setAr(cursor2.getString(3));
                        itemm.setFa(cursor2.getString(4));
                        itemm.setTr(cursor2.getString(5));
                        searcharray.add(itemm);
                    } while (cursor2.moveToNext());
                }
            }
            return searcharray;
        }
        private ArrayList<Item> fillList(String keyword) {
            ArrayList<Item> newarray;
            if (keyword.equals(BuildConfig.FLAVOR)) {
                newarray = new ArrayList();
            } else if (keyword.toCharArray().length < 2) {
                newarray = search(keyword);
            } else {
                newarray = search(keyword);
            }
            return newarray;
        }
        private void validateItemCount() {
            if (fillarary.size() == 0) {
                not_found.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                not_found.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Adapter is initialised using the ArrayList named myList.
Once after you get a value "searcharray" within your search function call this,

```
myList = searcharray;
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This will refresh the values that are in your list view with the search results.

Comment: also this did not fix the problem. It's about 3 hours I have been searching for one error, I can't find it but I don't know what is the problem. even I clean build the project, still nothing. it worked perfectly before but I don;t know what is the problem now.